# How to have python initiate a command the moment you push a button in the GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I researched this topic and could not find exactly what I needed to get the results I needed.  I am fairly new to Python and new to Tkinter, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Python code through the Raspberry Pi to control a Arduino Uno, which will ultimately control servos to control a remote control car.

I am using the GUI through Raspberry Pi and using Tkinter commands such as button to interact through the GUI.  The buttons are four, which are 'Up', 'Down' ,'left' and 'right'.

Right now I am using the Serial Monitor through the Sketch Arduino program to debug the code.

Although the code is working and is sending a signal to the Arduino, it is not working as I would have hoped. Right now it is initiating the command after you let go of the button and only for a moment.

What I need: For the signal to be sent to the Arduino the moment the button is pressed, and continue to send the signal as long as the button is being pressed and cut off as soon as the button is released.

Here is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import serial
running = True
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')


class Application(Frame):
    """Defining the remote control buttons"""
    def __init__(self,master):
        """Initialize the frame"""
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid() # How many times has the user clicked the button
        self.create_widgets()
   def create_widgets(self):
        """Creates four buttons that move the servos"""
        #Create the 'up' button
        self.bttn1 = ButtonPress(self)
        self.bttn1["text"] = "Up"
        self.bttn1["command"] = self.up
        self.bttn1.grid()

        #Create the 'down' button
        self.bttn2 = Button(self)
        self.bttn2.grid()
        self.bttn2["text"] = "Down"
        self.bttn2["command"] = self.down

        #Create the 'left' button
        self.bttn3 = Button(self)
        self.bttn3.grid()
        self.bttn3["text"] = "Left"
        self.bttn3["command"] = self.left

        #create the 'right' button
        self.bttn4 = Button(self)
        self.bttn4.grid()
        self.bttn4["text"] = "Right"
        self.bttn4["command"] = self.right
    #Tells python to send the data to Arduino via serial
    def right(self):
       ser.write('3')

    def left(self):
        ser.write('4')



    def up(self):
        ser.write('1')



    def down(self):
        ser.write('2')




#Main
root = Tk()
root.title("Remote control")
root.geometry("250x250")
app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can configure a button's `repeatdelay` and `repeatinterval` to trigger an action continuously while the button is pressed. See http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/button.html . For example, a button with `repeatinterval=10` will fire every ten milliseconds while it is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons in tkinter by default don't fire until you release the mouse button. However, you can set bindings on both a button press and a button release. You can make bindings that set a flag on press and unset it on release, and then create a function that sends data while the flag is set.

There are several ways to implement this. One way is to have a function that runs periodically, and sends the key if the button is pressed and doesn't if it's unset. Another way is to only have it run while the key is pressed. For simplicity's sake, I'll show the first method.

In this example I'll use the flag not only to determine *if* data should be sent, but also to define *what* data is to be sent. That is by no means a requirement, it just cuts down a little on how much code you have to write.

```
def send_data(self):
    if self.char is not None:
        ser.write(self.char)

    # run again in 100ms. Here is where you control how fast
    # to send data. The first parameter to after is a number
    # of milliseconds to wait before calling the function
    self.job = self.after(100, self.send_data)
```

The above code will run approximately every 100 milliseconds, sending whatever character is set (or nothing at all). At any time you can cancel this auto-running task with `self.after_cancel(self.job)`.

The buttons need to simply set or unset `self.char`. While it's unusual to use bindings rather than the `command` attribute for buttons, in this case that's exactly what you want.

Since the only difference between the buttons is what they send, all of the buttons can call the same function, passing in the character to be sent:

```
self.button1 = Button(self, text="Up")
self.button1.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda: self.set_char('1'))
self.button1.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda: self.set_char(None))

def set_char(self, char):
    self.char = char
```

Finally, you need to make sure you call `send_data` *exactly once*, and it will then run forever (or until cancelled with `after_cancel`)

```
class Application(Frame):
    """Defining the remote control buttons"""
    def __init__(self,master):
        ...
        self.char = None
        self.send_data()
```

Comment: Bryan Oakley: Ok. I tinkered with the code and now it appears that the numbers are not going through the serial port (USB).  The only thing I am thinking is going on is that the number are not getting through the serial port.  It appears that I can not post the code here, too long.